# IDE with library-referenced autocompletion, debugging, and running for Nodejs on mac

Tags: macos, debugging, node.js, ide, autocomplete

I am currently learning server-side javascript development using Node.js and would like to find an IDE that works well with it.

I have tried installing [Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/), for eclipse and Aptana, but these solutions don't completely do all of what I want.

I like how eclipse currently does autocompletion and shows compile-time errors for Java, and really like how the autocompletion is not just text-based but actually type-matched. Although Javascript doesn't have many types, I would still like relavant autocompletion options, and I think eclipse has that function already. I would like to use eclipse because it has a lot of the functionality built in, but if no solutions exist, I may go into my cave and try to build my own Nodejs IDE.

I appreciate any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from JetBrains. Auto-completion, intellisense, and they have support to run node.js interactively through their debugger. It's not free, but a personal license @ $49 or business license @ $99 is rather inexpensive.

Best thing is to try the download -- it's full-featured and runs for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

[netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is almost certainly worth looking at. If you're developing on linux, there's a [node plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36653/nodejs) which looks like it will allow you to run your node project directly from the IDE.

I haven't used netbeans for node development yet but have been using it on a front-end  project (HTML5, CSS, jQuery) I'm working on and have been really impressed with it. I had previously used Aptana and then Visual Studio and found both wanting in a number of areas. netbeans just seems to work and has none of the annoyances which caused me to ditch the other two.